# How to use Mahalanobis distance to find the K Nearest Neighbor in R

Tags: r, mahalanobis

I have a time series dataset from 1970 to 2020 as my training dataset, and I have another single observation of 2021, what I have to do right now is to use Mahalanobis distance to identify 10 nearest neighbor of 2021 in training dataset. I tried several function like `get.knn()` and `get.knnx()`, but I failed to set distance as Mahalanobis distance. Is there any function that i can use? Thank you in advance!

------------------edit--------------------

So I tried function of `mahalanobis()` and then I got a list of values, are these values the mahalanobis distance? Can I sort them to get the top 10?

Comment: Please provide reproducible data and show your code.

Comment: Try `biotools` package. It also has some mahalanobis functions

Answer (score 0):

### Background

The Mahalanobis distance measures how far a point is away from the mean, measured in standard deviations, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance). It uses eigenvalue rotated coordinates and is related to pricipal component analysis. Cross Validated contains several excellent explanations, e.g. this ["bottom-to-top-explanation"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62092/bottom-to-top-explanation-of-the-mahalanobis-distance/62147) or a [function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65705/pairwise-mahalanobis-distances) (`cholMaha`, see below) how to estimate a distance matrix.

### Relationship of Mahalanobis distance to PCA

Let's assume a small data example:

```r
A <- data.frame(
  x = c(-2.48, -4.03, 1.15, 0.94, 5.33, 4.72),
  y = c(-3.92, -3.4, 0.92, 0.78, 3.44, 0.5),
  z = c(-1.11, -2.18, 0.21, 0.34, 1.74, 1.12)
)
```

Then we can estimate the Mahalanobis distance matrix via `D2.dist`from package **biotools** or the above mentioned function:

```r
## Mahalanobis distance from package biotools
library("biotools")
# sqrt, because D2.dist returns squared version
sqrt(D2.dist(A, cov(A)))


## https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65705/pairwise-mahalanobis-distances

cholMaha <- function(X) {
  dec <- chol( cov(X) )
  tmp <- forwardsolve(t(dec), t(X) )
  dist(t(tmp))
}

cholMaha(A)
```

Now comes the point. We can also estimate the **Mahalanobis distance** as the **euclidean distance** of the re-scaled loadings (rotated data) of a principal components analysis:

```r
## derive Mahalanobis distance from principal components
pc <- prcomp(A)     # principal components
AA <- scale(pc$x)   # "upscale" all components to the same level

# Euclidean distance of rescaled PC transformed variables is identical to
# Mahalanobis distance
dist(AA)
```

The result is identical to the two approaches above.

### Application to a classification algorithm

One can now use this relation in any classification algorithm. Just transform the data matrix by PCA rotation and fit their euclidean distances in.

```r
## Now apply this in any classification method, e.g. hclust
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))

# Euclidean distance of original variables
plot(hclust(dist(scale(A))), main="Euclidean")

# Euclidean distance of scaled principal components
# is equivalent to Mahalanobis distance; considers covariance
plot(hclust(dist(AA)), main="Mahalanobis")
```

In effect, small influece factors hidden in the variables are upscaled, but unfortunately also random errors. To understand this in detail, read the ["My grandma cooks"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/62105) answer at Cross Validated.